# React TypeScript ClickListener and querySelector

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I always get the error `'querySelector' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'`.

```
 const onClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const elem = event.target.querySelector('.elem')
    const elem1 = event.target.querySelector('.elem1')
    elem.classList.toggle('active')
    elem1.classList.toggle('active')
  }
```

Comment: i think this is anti-pattern in react. have you looked at using refs?

Comment: I think there is no need for me to use ref here, because I'm using event.target and I'm not selecting an element directly using querySeclector, so there is no side effect

Answer (score 0):

event object on react is not the actually the same as the DOM. It's a [synthetic](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) one which is recycled by React. it's an antipattern to use it to query a specific element. the correct way to handle would be for you to toggle an `active` boolean state as:

```
 const onClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    // if you are using classes:
    this.setState(prevState => ({active: !prevState.active}))

    // if you are using hooks:
    setActive(prevActive => !prevActive)
    // or
    setActive(!active)
  }
```

than at your elements you would have something like that would evaluate `active` state:

```
// && operator acts as a shortcut, and 'active' will be only be returned if active state is truthy
// for class component:
<div className={this.state.active && 'active'}>elm</div>
// for hook component:
<div className={active && 'active'}>elm</div>
```